# Return an array of type Self

Tags: ios, swift

I'm having trouble figuring out a way to return an array of instances of a specific dynamic class type, at runtime, in Swift.

I successfully compiled and tested this version which returns a single instance of a class:

```
class Generic {

    class func all() -> Self {
        return self.init()
    }

    required init() {

    }

}

class A: Generic {

}

let a = A.all() // is of type A
```

The challenge here is to get compilation to allow the `all` function to be prototyped as follows: `class func all() -> [Self]` (i.e return an array of instances, working with subclasses, **without any cast**).

```
class Generic {

    class func all() -> [Self] {
        return [self.init()]
    }

    required init() {

    }

}

class A: Generic {

}

let a = A.all() // won't compile
```

I could return an array of `Generic` instances with `class func all() -> [Generic]` but this requires an additional cast with `as!` to get the correct type `A`. I'd like to take advantage of begin in the context of class `A` and using the `Self` keyword, to let the compiler infer the 'real' type. Do you guys think it's possible?

It seems to be only possible to return single instances, not arrays.

**EDIT**: Got this to work using `AnyObject`. Better, but not optimal as it requires a cast to the correct type.

```
class Generic {

    class func all() -> [AnyObject] {
        return [self.init()]
    }

    required init() {

    }

}

class A: Generic {

}

let a = A.all() as! [A]
```

Thanks!

PS: Any other way to do this using generics or protocols/protocol extensions is also an option. If you have a more "Swifty" version in mind, please be my guest. Can't help myself thinking there's maybe a better way to do this, but can't figure out how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only option I can see of doing something like that is using protocols instead of a base class, like this:

```
protocol Generic {

    func all() -> [Self]

    init()

}

extension Generic {

    func all() -> [Self] {
        return [self.dynamicType.init()]
    }

}

final class A : Generic {

}

A().all()
```

You have two limitations doing it like this. First, all classes that conform to your protocol have to be final. Second, all classes must obviously implement the init defined in the protocol, otherwise we wouldn't be able to have the `all` method defined.

Edit: you don't actually need to define the init as long as you don't define any other initializers

Edit 2: I didn't notice you used class functions, you can modify my example to use class functions instead of instance methods by replacing `func all() -> [Self]` with `static func all() -> [Self]` and

```
func all() -> [Self] {
    return [self.dynamicType.init()]
}
```

with

```
static func all() -> [Self] {
    return [self.init()]
}
```

Comment: Seems definitely better than my version! The only drawback is like you said the need to implement `init` in every subclasses.

Comment: You are not actually using a class method there.

Comment: actually, I was wrong. every class starts with an automatically defined empty initializer, so as long as you don't define another initializer, it works just fine

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a way to do this using `Self`. `Self` cannot be used in expressions, so `[Self]` or `Array<Self>` are not allowed.

However, I think that your use case is completely valid and you should repot it as a bug.

Comment: That's a shame :( Do you think there any way to have a class method return instances of itself, but keeping the inference work with every subclass, maybe using generics? Can't help myself thinking it can be done with generics, or protocols/protocol extensions in Swift 2.0, but can figure out a way to do that.